# openapi-generator not generating model

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using the openapi-generator to create a multipart/form-data. In an ideal situation I should be able to upload a file, and specify in the options what should happen with the file.

I would like the options to be an object. For one or another reason, this does not seem to work. The openapi-generator generates the API interface, etc, but it does not generate the model for the options object.

I can specify the options individually, but I prefer the options to be an object, with the necessary model to it. I believe this provides a more structured way to deal with the options.

My yaml file looks like this (I specified what works and what doesn't work):

```
  /fileuploadwithoptions:
    post:
      summary: Upload a file and processes it according to the options specified.
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              required:
                - file
              type: object
              properties:
                file:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
                option1:  <-- this works
                  type: string
                  description: A descriptions for option 1.
                options: <-- this does not work
                  #type: application/json
                  type: object
                  description: The options.
                  properties:
                    option1:
                      type: string
                      description: A descriptions for option 1.
                    option2:
                      type: string
                      description: A descriptions for option 2.
            encoding:
              file:
                contentType: application/octet-stream
```

This generates the following API:

```
/**
 * NOTE: This class is auto generated by OpenAPI Generator (https://openapi-generator.tech) (6.0.1).
 * https://openapi-generator.tech
 * Do not edit the class manually.
 */
package com.teradact.tokenizerplusserver.api;

import com.teradact.tokenizerplusserver.model.FileuploadwithoptionsPostRequestOptions;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameters;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityRequirement;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.annotation.Generated;

@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2022-10-11T08:11:04.909499+02:00[Europe/Brussels]")
@Validated
@Tag(name = "fileuploadwithoptions", description = "the fileuploadwithoptions API")
public interface FileuploadwithoptionsApi {

    default Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    /**
     * POST /fileuploadwithoptions : Upload a file and processes it according to the options specified.
     *
     * @param file  (required)
     * @param option1 A descriptions for option 1. (optional)
     * @param options  (optional)
     * @return The file. (status code 200)
     *         or bad input parameter (status code 400)
     */
    @Operation(
        operationId = "fileuploadwithoptionsPost",
        summary = "Upload a file and processes it according to the options specified.",
        responses = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "The processed file.", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/octet-stream", schema = @Schema(implementation = org.springframework.core.io.Resource.class))
            }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "bad input parameter")
        }
    )
    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        value = "/fileuploadwithoptions",
        produces = { "application/octet-stream" },
        consumes = { "multipart/form-data" }
    )
    default ResponseEntity<org.springframework.core.io.Resource> fileuploadwithoptionsPost(
        @Parameter(name = "file", description = "", required = true) @RequestPart(value = "file", required = true) MultipartFile file,
        @Parameter(name = "option1", description = "A descriptions for option 1.") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "option1", required = false) String option1,
        @Parameter(name = "options", description = "") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "options", required = false) FileuploadwithoptionsPostRequestOptions options
    ) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }

}
```

This gives however the following error:

"Cannot resolve symbol 'FileuploadwithoptionsPostRequestOptions", since the model for the object is simply not created.

Thanks in advance for pointing out where I am wrong!

Comment: Looking at the documentation https://swagger.io/specification/#considerations-for-file-uploads change your `options` "`properties`" to "`items`" then that can have a type which can also be a reference to a complex object

Answer (score 0):

The interface has the name 'FileuploadwithoptionsApi', YAML file has /fileuploadwithoptions and the response entity has name fileuploadwithoptionsPost but the RequestParam has object 'FileuploadwithoptionsPostRequestOptions' is it because of this it cannot resolve the symbol.

```
@Parameter(name = "options", description = "") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "options", required = false) FileuploadwithoptionsPostRequestOptions options)
```

Is the object 'FileuploadwithoptionsPostRequestOptions' instantiated or does it have a similar class or interface matching the object present in @Request Param.

Ok, you have imported the required class for the object try using @RequestPart as you have used for file. Try if it works.